# How to fix multiple reboot issue after joining domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

I'm seeing that after joining machines to a specific ADA domain that the computers require you to reboot twice. Not to join domain but for any reboot ever. This only happens after it has joined domain. I see this when attempting to reboot in event viewer:

attempt to reboot failed user32

I've not seen anything in GPO to cause this. Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Comment: You sure there isn’t any other events that point to WSUS or GPO (Software Installation) policies? Also how long is the time between the reboots? Is it also dual rebooting before it logs back into the desktop for the client?

Comment: You click reboot and nothing seems to happen except the event. Click it again and it reboots normally.

Comment: There is nothing inherent in joining a machine to a domain that will cause reboot attempts to fail.  Does this behavior persist if you clean-boot the machine, then attempt to reboot it?

Comment: I'll test this tomorrow to see. The machines reboot fine until added to domain. There are no WSUS or software installation policies after further review. There are actually no policies targeted to the machines. The default domain policy was for some reason targeted to only two servers and then there is a default dc policy and nothing else.